# Server is down after changing machine type in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: centos7, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform

I changed my machine type(GCP) by stopping the instance, after increasing the machine type I restarted the instance and now server stopped working, the website is down now.
Upgraded from  **1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory** to **2 vCPU, 4GB memory**.
And if I select other than **1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory**, the webserver doesn't respond.
Also, I can't access SSH from a web browser it gives me an error that "Connection Failed. We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22."

Log:  https://pastebin.pl/view/2af02149

Comment: Have you changed the default SSH port on the VM?

Comment: @ChristopherH No, I didn't change that

Answer (score 1):

How to [Handle the "Unable to connect on port 22" error message](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror) OR create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the troubled instance and use that [snapshot to create an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot).